# Missing achievement in AnswerSwarm

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answer-swarm

I had a bounty on this question: [What are the new units in Heart of the Swarm?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106408/what-are-the-new-units-in-heart-of-the-swarm) which was awarded during the AnswerSwarm period.

Doesn't look like I have the 'My Precioussss' achievement. Any admins have access to check?

Comment: Hm. I'd wager it's because the question it was awarded on was asked before the contest date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Raven Dreamer points out, only posts made after the start of the AnswerSwarm promo are eligible. From the rules:

> Only questions tagged [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) and answers to those questions **that were posted during the contest count**. Closed and/or deleted questions are disqualified from consideration.

Emphasis added.

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: There were some related nuances to the Diablo 3 competition, which can be frustrating.  I think contests should in all ways seek to encourage good user behavior, and in this case users who curate existing out of date content get punished - even though this is a behavior we very much want to encourage.  Given that we made a ruling that HotS and WoL are [***the same game***](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7005/shouldnt-starcraft-2-and-starcraft-2-hots-be-split-now-that-heart-of-the-s?cb=1), the date limit for bounties and edits seems like a bad fit.